# How to paste chinese characters in psql terminal?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, psql

I am trying to paste chinese characters into psql terminal:

```
$ psql
=> \encoding
=> UTF8
# Ctrl+v (艺术与设计)
=> ?????设计
```

When pasting into normal terminal (Max OS) it works fine:

```
$ # Ctrl+v (艺术与设计)
$ 艺术与设计
```

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`psql` delegates the handling of input to a shared library, which is either `libreadline` or `libedit`.

But `libedit` used to not work reliably with multibyte character sets, as has been reported on multiple occasions, [here for OSX for example](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/ED7A6905-C6F4-4AE2-AED4-B654FCE15765@salk.edu).

From your comment:

> `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/psql -> libedit@1.47.0` does not work, `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/psql -> libedit@1.48.0` does not work BUT `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/psql -> libedit@3.0.0` works!

...it seems that by relinking to a newer version, you were able to solve the problem. That's useful to know.

The reason why `libedit` is used at all while `libreadline` did a better job first is that the latter is licensed under the GPL, whereas `psql` is BSD-licensed like the rest of PostgreSQL. A consequence is that `psql` cannot be shipped in compiled form with the necessary parts that call `libreadline`, without breaching its license. On the other hand `libedit` uses the BSD license, so it's OK to ship with it.

The solution for psql packagers so far has been to ship PostgreSQL with `libedit` and let the users relink it with `libreadline` if necessary.

On Linux, the Debian/Ubuntu packages even do this dynamically without the user intervening.